# Change List Webpart View (Not Filter) using Page Querystring

Tags: list, web-part, list-view

I have a list webpart on a page. I also have a Query String (URL) Filter and am able to filter the list view based on a QS parameter.

What I would like to do though is change the webpart 'group-by' field. I figure the best way is to set up a view for each group-by I want to use and then use a QS parameter to set which view is shown.

Can you change the view of a list webpart using the Query String? (to be clear I want to change the view e.g. from AllItems to View1, View2 etc, not just filter by a column).

Comment: Just to add - I don't have access to SP Designer due to governance sorry!